# Parse JSON to struct with one function

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I can't find any answer on how to parse json from response `Data` object automatically if we know the response type. I'm quite new to swift, therefore my solution may be not ideal, but I believe it does what it was supposed to do - parse `Data` to swift struct with just one short line of code.

First, I extended `Decodable` protocol

```swift
extension Decodable {
    static func parse(from data: Data) -> Self?{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let json = try? decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
        return json
    }
}
```

then if I define example struct

```swift
struct Example: Decodable {
    let a: String
    let b: Int
}
```

and have some data

```swift
let data = """
{"a": "Test", "b": 5}
""".data(using: .utf8)
print(Example.parse(from: data!))
```

I wanted to have automatically parsed response while could not find such answer on the Internet.
Of course, we need to take care of `nil` and `Example` object is Optional, but this can be handled by external function.
Is there any reason why this code is not safe, or for whatever reason not recommended to use?

Answer (score 2):

Typically this isn't done because it assumes that the only format the data can be encoded in is JSON (Codable supports other formats), and that you never intend to configure the decoder (Decoders have several configuration options).

Your code also throws away JSON parsing errors, which is not ideal, though may be convenient for some uses.

If your project never has any of those issues, and you want a shorter syntax for your special case, then it's fine to add any extension you like. That's what extensions are for.

I would suggest you rethink the `try?` however. Throwing away errors and turning them into nil makes debugging much harder. But again, it's up to you. Build any extension that is convenient for you.

Comment: I believe I could change method name to `parseToJson` and if needed add another one `parseToWhatever`. I am not really familiar with swift yet, what would you suggest to swap `try?` to?

Comment: Use `try`. And if you're new to Swift, I recommend against this extension. It's not a common solution. Just create a decoder when you need it (possibly reusing the decoder if you have many things to decode), decode the things you need, and catch any errors (or mark the function `throws` and handle them elsewhere). See the docs for JSONDecoder. That example is fine and how it's usually done.